# IO error when piping email to python

Tags: python, email, piping

I have cpanel set to pipe emails to a python script.  I will eventually have to write to files with this script, so I am trying a very basic script now.

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import sys
def main():
    y = open("mail.txt", "a")
    for line in sys.stdin:
        y.write(str(line))
    y.close()
main()
```

When I pipe something to it from the command line, it works fine, but I when I send an email to it, it bounces back with an IO error.

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'mail.txt'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like you can't open the file due to permissions.  Have you checked those?

Comment: Check that `os.getcwd()` and `os.getuid()` produce values that you expect. `str(line)` is redundant. Instead of `source_cmd | python -myour_script`, you could run `source_cmd >>mail.txt`

Comment: I found the problem. It was trying to save mail.txt to the python directory, so I had to specify the exact location for the file to be stored in the y = open... line.